# How to define mediumtext datatype using Apache embedded derby database

Tags: java, derby

I am trying to define `MEDIUMTEXT` datatype declaration, here i am using apache embedded derby dabase.
When I try to execute SQL query it is giving exception need some help in tackling this problem.

My code:

```
statement s= s.execute("create table t(data MEDIUMTEXT)");
```

Answer (score 2):

MEDIUMTEXT is not listed as a [supported datatype in the reference manual](https://builds.apache.org/job/Derby-docs/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/out/ref/crefsqlj31068.html)

Comment: thanks for your reply 
well is there a datatype which store's large text, i tried to use varchar(40000) which gives an exception whereas varchar(30000) gives no exception but i what a datatype which stores large text

Answer (score 1):

I would use CLOB data type for long text in Derby.

Answer (score 0):

well i figured it out i can use CLOB INSTEAD OF MEDIUMTEXT which allows to store text upto 2GB